# chose what value an object with two array options should chose

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem where I have a deck of cards going from 2-10, and dressed cards are worth 10 and ace is worth 1 or 11 depending on the total value of the hand.

I'm trying to create a blackjack game, I'm using first an array of all the cards and then randomly picks a card. then I convert it to a value in 'cardsMap' (all dressed cards are worth 10) but is the ace that I have an issue with as I don't know how I can determine its value or make it chose the right index if the total value of the hand would go over 21.

my current code is:

```js
blackjackGame = {
  'you': 0,
  'dealer': 0,
  'cards': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'],
  'cardsMap': {
    'A': [1, 11],
    '2': 2,
    '3': 3,
    '4': 4,
    '5': 5,
    '6': 6,
    '7': 7,
    '8': 8,
    '9': 9,
    '10': 10,
    'J': 10,
    'Q': 10,
    'K': 10
  },
}



function totalValue(player, card) {
  // this is where i have no ieda what to  do
  //---------------------------------------
  let pose = card.indexOf('A')

  card.forEach(function(item, index, array) {

    if (item === 'A') {
      if (player + card[pose[1]] < 21) {
        return player += card[pose[1]]
        console.log('less than 21')
      } else if (player + card[pose[1]] > 21) {
        return player += card[pose[0]]
        console.log('over 21')
      }
    } else {
      return player += card
    }

  });

  // sum up all the cards that are on the hand
  //-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
  player = card.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + blackjackGame['cardsMap'][b];
  }, 0);

  return player
}
```

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't return anything, and a `return` in the callback of `.forEach()` will only stop that one interation but not the whole `.forEach()`. Use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you , when ever you calculate the total points be it for player or dealer , make sure if there is an Ace card , add it at the end , so that it is easy to decide for you . If you need , I can provide the sample code

Comment: I would very much like that if it isn't a problem